# Certbot Apache Augeas installation error

Tags: apache-http-server, httpd, letsencrypt, certbot

I have a Centos7 server with apache 2 and certbot installed.  I ran an update that may have broken the configuration.  I keep getting an error when trying to renew my cert.  It says:

Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
The apache plugin is not working; there may be problems with your existing configuration.
The error was: NoInstallationError('Problem in Augeas installation',)

httpd -t
AH00548: NameVirtualHost has no effect and will be removed in the next release /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:96
AH00526: Syntax error on line 9 of /etc/httpd/sites-available/*************
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/letsencrypt/live/***************/cert.pem' does not exist or is empty

Any assistance is appreciated.

I verified that the file cert file does exist.  I'm wondering if the problem could be that apache does not have readd access to the file.

The update command used was a sudo yum update.

Comment: Have you attempted to see if `/etc/letsencrypt/live/***************/cert.pem` exists? Likewise, have you checked your configurations for Apache, Cerbot, etc.? What update did you run that you think may have broke the installation? Please edit this question and provide more details.

Comment: Have you (temporarily) tried disabling selinux - My bet is that you need to relabel the filesystem as selinux is preventing that file from being read.   Either that or the owner and/or file perms are wrong on the cert.